# Mysql query NOT EXISTS doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database, not-exists

I have the following two tables and columns

Table 1: transactionid

Table 2: transactionid and status

I need to get results from the table 1 if the same transactionid doesn't exist in table2

If the same transactionid in table2 exists but the status is different than 2 then it shouldn't return the table1 row

If the same transactionid in table2 exists and the status is 2 then it should return the table 1 row but i need to know this so i can show an error inside my website

I currently have:

```
select * from table1 where not exists (select null from table2
            WHERE table1.transactionid = table2.transactionid AND status <> 2)
```

i would need something like this (it doesn't work properly)

```
select *, (select count(*) from table2 where table1.transactionid = table2.transactionid AND status = 2) as orderswitherrors from table1 where not exists (select null from table2
            WHERE table1.transactionid = table2.transactionid AND status <> 2)
```

So in php i can check if that transactionid has an error in table2 with if ($row->orderswitherrors > 0) ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are troubling yourself too much by trying to use EXISTS.

In this query, we just use a join to get both Table1 and Table2 into the resultset.  We use a left join, so that rows from Table1 will be returned even if they do not exist in Table2.  If there isn't a matching row, the resultset will contain NULL for all the Table2 columns.

Once we have a resultset that has both tables in it, we just filter our those rows so that we only keep rows where a) there is no row from Table2, or (b) there is a row and the status = 2.

```
SELECT    table1.*, 
          table2.status
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.transactionid = table2.transactionid
WHERE     table2.transactionid IS NULL   --Doesn't exist in table2
OR        table2.status = 2              --Exists in table2 with status 2
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/dojSZ Thanks for the help, however i need to don't return any results if there is a status 1 in one of the rows in table2. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'left join' along with `case` statement to get transaction id with state, and show/hide errors based on state e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.transactionid, 
CASE WHEN t2.status IS NULL THEN 'NOT_EXISTS'
WHEN t2.status = 2 THEN 'ERROR'
END AS state
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.transactionid = t2.transactionid
WHERE t2.status IS NULL OR t2.status = 2
ORDER BY t1.transactionid;
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/076a7/11/0)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and `EXISTS` in combination:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.transactionid = t2.transactionid
                 ) or
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.transactionid = t2.transactionid and
                    status = 2
             );
```